# Выборка из postgres записей в соответствии с массивом id (с сохрененим порядка)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby

Есть массив с айдишниками объектов, например

```
a = [10, 5, 6, 8, 4]
```

Мне необходимо выбрать элементы коллекции с такими айдишниками и в таком же порядке. Делаю:

```
@pics = Picture.where(id: a)
```

Но в итоге получаю порядок элементов не такой как в массиве. Хотя по логу читаю, что запрос идет нужный:

```
 Picture Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."id" IN (10, 5, 6, 8, 4)
```

А если перебрать @pics , то там порядок айдишников будет другой. Помогите, это особенность постгреса? или я что-то делаю не так?

Update: `.order(a)` тоже не помогает

Comment: Пока базе данных не указан явно порядок сортировки, она имеет право вернуть данные в любом порядке.

Comment: как тогда правильно выполнить мою задачу?

Comment: указать явно порядок сортировки

Comment: А если не могу? Сортировка ни по одному из полей мне не подходит.

Comment: `[10, 5, 6, 8, 4]` - это у вас не порядок сортировки? Вы не можете отсортировать полученные данные по нему уже после их возврата из БД?

Comment: не могу, поэтому и спрашиваю здесь. Делаю `.order(a)` - все равно порядок не тот получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить двумя способами. 
Средствами Ruby можно отсортировать итоговый массив:

```
@pics.sort_by!{|i| a.index i.id}
```

И средствами SQL. Если бы вы использовали MySQL, то можно было воспользоваться оператором FIELD:

```
@pics = Picture.where(id: a).order("FIELD(id, #{a.join(', )})")
```

В PostgreSQL оператор FIELD не поддерживается, но его можно эмулировать (подробнее [тут](https://gist.github.com/cpjolicoeur/3590737)).
В вашем случае код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
order = a.map.with_index{ |k,v| "(#{k}, #{v})"}.join(', ')
@pics = Picture.where(id: a).joins("JOIN (VALUES #{order}) as x(id, ordering) ON pictures.id = x.id").order('x.ordering')
```